# Difficulty Connecting To SQL Server Express 2012 from VB.NET (Express)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to connect to a locally installed instance of SQL Server 2012 Express using VB.NET. I have been able to successfully connect to the database using the drag-and-drop connection tool, which gives me this connection string:

```
Data Source=mycomputername\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog="my space containing database name";Integrated Security=True
```

I can successfully test this connection. Now, I want to populate a datagrid from a table in this database, so in the "root" (what do you really call this place?) of the project I have:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

and in the form definition (before any event handlers) I have

```
Private cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=mycomputername\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=[my space containing database name];Integrated Security=True;")
Private da As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from MyTable", cn)
Private ds As New DataSet
Private cmb As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
```

And this is where the train goes off the tracks. I get the error:

> Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login.
>   The login failed. Login failed for user 'MyLogin'.

I have made sure that SQL Server Express has the Remote Login check box checked, and tried other variations on the connection string, but no luck. Ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ASP.NET? It's possible that your application runs under a different user than your visual studio (Integrated Security uses your windows authentication, based on the user your application is impersonating - in a web application, that's usually someone like NETWORK SERVICE). You'd just have to add this user as one of the users of your SQL server and database.

**EDIT**: I see it now. '\s' is a special character in a string.
use this as your connection string:

```
"Data Source=mycomputername\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=[my space containing database name];Integrated Security=True;"
```

**EDIT**: No, my bad, you're using VB, this kind of escaping is used in C#.

Comment: I'm making a Windows Forms application in VB.NET, so I don't know if this applies - the error message gives my correct login as the one that failed to connect, so I am thinking that that part is OK

Comment: @MrBill: Can you connect to the database using Management Studio?

Comment: Yes, no trouble there

Comment: The extra backslash angered SQL Server - I got "Instance Failure"

Comment: Oh, my bad. I forgot you're using Visual Basic. Never mind then.